# Flot - bar chart with individual colors and labels

Tags: jquery, flot, bar-chart

I use [flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/) to display simple bar charts. I have single dataset like `[ [0,5], [1,6], [2,3], [4,1] ]` and I am using this simple code:

```
myChart = $.plot($('#graphFlot'), [{
        data: mdata,
        bars: { show: true, fill: 0.9 }
    }]
   );
```

Now I would like to display various colors and labels for each bar.
Example bar chart [here](http://www.mathsrevision.net/gcse/barchart.gif) is how it  should look like.

I've browsed through many examples and documentation and still do not know how to set this. Is this possible?

Comment: I actually managed to get this done with Flotr2 :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put each bar in its own series and give each series a different label.

Comment: I have been just thinking about that, I am going to give it a try.

Comment: Looks like you beat me to it :).

Answer (score 1):

var mdata = [ [0,5], [1,6], [2,3], [4,1]];
var bar_array = [];

$.each(mdata, function(i, bar) {
    bar_array.push({
        data: [bar],
        bars: { show: true, fill:0.9 }
    });
});

myChart = $.plot($('#graphFlot'), bar_array);

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge there's no setting in Flot or Flotr2 that allows you to do this. I managed to get this done by making changes to the code that renders the barchart in flotr2.js