# Unique colors for flot bar chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, flot, bar-chart

I want to create a flot bar chart that will display true and false figures, like my example below.
I want the true bar to be green and the false one to be red. I've tried using the colors array but it doesn't work properly.

My current code:

```
var options3 = {grid: {hoverable: true},series: {bars: {show: true,barWidth: 0.6,align: "center"}},yaxis: {min:0,tickSize: 1},xaxis: {mode: "categories",ticks: [ [0, 'True'], [1, 'False'] ],tickLength: 0},tooltip: true,tooltipOpts: {content: '%y Votes', defaultTheme: false}, colors: [ "#FF0000", "#00FF00"]};
var data3 = [ [0, 3], [1, 9] ];
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.plot('#graph3', [data3], options3);
});
```

<strike>Example: http://joshblease.co.uk/Maths/Admin/chart.php#graph3</strike>

Comment: What's your question again?  In the linked example, true is green and false is red, so what's the problem?

Comment: @Mark I eventually went and figured it out myself whilst I was messing with that example

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flot - bar chart with individual colors and labels](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11827404/flot-bar-chart-with-individual-colors-and-labels)

Comment: -1. this is a poor question - the example code is not formatted nicely and needless to say the external link is out of date.  The single answer given is correct but hasn't been marked as so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have only one data series, which is assigned the first color in your array (red). You will get the result you want if you replace

```
var data3 = [ [0, 3], [1, 9] ];
```

with

```
var data3 = [
    [[0, 3]],
    [[1, 9]]
];
```

Then use `data3` in the plot instead of `[data3]`. See the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pWbyv/).