# Flot, different bar colours?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, flot

I am using Flot to draw a bar chart.
I was wondering how I can get each bar to have a different colour. I have seen the threshold plugin but I don't think that is what I am after.

For example:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSnJh.png

(Excuse the poor paint skills)

I currently pass the graph data in the format:

```
[[1, 1],[2, 2],[3, 3],[4, 4],[5, 5]]
```

via my mvc controller:

```
return Json(new[] 
{ 
new[] { 1, 1 }, 
new[] { 2, 2 }, 
new[] { 3, 3 }, 
new[] { 4, 4 }, 
new[] { 5, 5 } 
},JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flot - bar chart with individual colors and labels](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11827404/flot-bar-chart-with-individual-colors-and-labels)

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone stumbles upon this.

Return the data from the controller in the following format:

```
var data = new[]
{
    new { data = new[]{ new[]{1, 1}}, color = "grey" },
    new { data = new[]{ new[]{2, 2}}, color = "red" },
    new { data = new[]{ new[]{3, 3}}, color = "orange" },
    new { data = new[]{ new[]{4, 4}}, color = "green" },
    new { data = new[]{ new[]{5, 5}}, color = "blue" }
};
return Json(data , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```